# Unable to fill in some date inputs to perform a customized search

Tags: vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11, queryselector

I'm trying to create a script in vba to select dates according to my preferable `input date`, as in `03/11/2019` and `output date`, as in `05/11/2019` for the two fields `check-in` and `chek-out`. the macro that I've written so far can click on those fields but can't fill in the inputs with the aforesaid dates.

[Website address](https://www.discoverqatar.qa/)

I've tried:

```
Sub FillInTheForm()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, elem As Object, guest As Object
    Dim findbtn As Object, URL$

    URL = "https://www.discoverqatar.qa/"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        Set post = .document.querySelector("[class='rsp_s_checkindate_input'] > #lpPannel_txtFromDate")
        post.Focus
        post.Click

        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        Set elem = .document.querySelector("[class='rsp_s_checkoutdate_input'] > #lpPannel_txtToDate")
        elem.Focus
        elem.Click

        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        Set guest = .document.querySelector("#lblPaxInfo")
        guest.Focus
        guest.Click

        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        Set findbtn = .document.querySelector("input#btnSearch")
        findbtn.Focus
        findbtn.Click
    End With
'    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Some intentional delays are there within the script which I can kick out later defining any timed loop.

> How can I fill in the dates in those boxes to perform a customized search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the value attributes

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SetDates()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.discoverqatar.qa/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#lpPannel_txtFromDate").Value = "03/11/2019"
            .querySelector("#lpPannel_txtToDate").Value = "05/11/2019"
            .querySelector("#btnSearch").Click
            Stop
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Although the macro appears to be working in the right way, the result is different from what I see when I do the same manually @QHarr. When I try manually I get `22` results whereas the macro gives me `28`. How can I fix it? ***[This is](https://pastebin.com/rCasfSbb)*** what my current approah is. Here goes ***[an image](https://filebin.net/iwgti260elqrpwlq)*** which shows how the filled-in boxes look like before clicking on the find button. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. I am working at moment but will update asap for you (provided I find solution).

Comment: Haven't forgotten this. Tonight will look.

Comment: Well done. Do you still want me to look at this then?

Comment: No need to guarantee me. Vote as you usually would. I will look at your docs though seems to be an .rar so will need to remind myself how I open those.

Comment: Okay, [this link](https://filebin.net/k4vz60h2vh0uu254) will help. Thanks.

Comment: ok.. how urgent is this? I have another OP who asked a follow-up as well. Does it need to be today or can it wait until potentially fri/sat?

Comment: Hey QHarr, it's not a matter of urgency. The thing is I can't take a breather unless I can disentangle any issue. I can accomplish the same using selenium but in case of IE the pain is ongoing which is difficult to endure. Thanks.

Comment: I understand. I’ll have a look today.

Comment: Will you be around to answer question and should I open a chat room for us?

Comment: Sure. Sorry for my belated response.

Comment: Dteleted some comments to make some space. Please inform me when you create a chat room as this is gonna be my first time and I don't know anything about this chat room. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201960/discussion-between-qharr-and-mithu).